# Formatting GRPC handlers in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, grpc

I´m new to GRPC and I´d like to learn about error formatting using gRPC and NodeJS.

Whenever we need to build a request handler for a gRPC server, we follow this pattern:

```
 * getFeature request handler. Gets a request with a point, and responds with a
 * feature object indicating whether there is a feature at that point.
 * @param {EventEmitter} call Call object for the handler to process
 * @param {function(Error, feature)} callback Response callback
 */
function getFeature(call, callback) {
  callback(null, checkFeature(call.request));
}
```

It´s clear to me what the call parameter is, and how to use callbacks.

My question is, how is the first field of the callback supossed to look like?
I think there is no error standard in nodeJS, and it seems like this should be a gRPC specific format.

I´ve looked around and there is a standard of [gRPC status codes](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/core/md_doc_statuscodes.html). Is that the error field? an int representing the status or a 0 (or nothing) if everything wet ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options there. Like most callback-based asynchronous APIs in JavaScript, that callback accepts a regular JS `Error` object. That will translate into an `UNKNOWN` status code. You can also set the `code` property on the error object to a member of the `grpc.status` enum. For example you can do `error.code = grpc.status.NOT_FOUND` to send a "Not found" error. In addition, you can set the `metadata` property on the error object to an instance of the `grpc.Metadata` class to send additional trailing metadata along with the error.

On top of all of that, you can also pass a simple object with a `details` string and `code` and `metadata` properties that are the same as described above. For example:

```js
callback({details: "Entry not found", code: grpc.status.NOT_FOUND});
```

Note that if everything goes OK, that error parameter should just be `null`.

Comment: Gotcha thanks! I was defining an error message in all my proto files this makes much more sense